# nginx: Append to proxied URL with proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, php, proxypass

I'm dealing with some legacy issues where I have to reconfigure servers hosting a PHP based application. One of the decisions was to move away from Apache onto Nginx.

Now the application hosts two kinds of responses;

```
/some/path -> HTML templates
/api/some/path -> JSON
```

The application is based on Laravel. Now, I have two virtual hosts, `my.app.com` and `api.app.com`. What I've thought of as a decent solution is to have `api.app.com` proxy the requests to `my.app.com` with a `/api` prepended to the request path. So;

```
GET api.app.com/user -> NGINX PROXY -> my.app.com/api/user
```

I'm no expert at Nginx configuration and this is what I think should work:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://my.app.com:8888/api;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}
```

The idea is to ensure that people trying to GET from `api.app.com/something` actually get a response from `my.app.com/api/something`
But that doesn't work. I keep getting exceptions from the app saying that the path cannot be found in the routes.

Can anyone tell me what's going on here?

Comment: Sounds like [you need a rewrite directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass).

Answer (score 0):

A tip from https://serverfault.com/a/586607:

```
location ~ /(?<path>.*) {
    proxy_pass http://my.app.com:8888/api/$path;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}
```

Comment: If the question is a duplicate - please flag it as such.