# NGINX Proxy_Pass remove url substring

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, regex

I have one NGINX acting as reverse proxy. I need to remove a substring string_1 from the URL, the rest of the URL is variable.

Example:

```
Origin: http://host:port/string_1/string_X/command?xxxxx

Destination: http://internal_host:port/string_X/command?xxxxx
```

nginx.conf:

```
location /string_1/   { 

    proxy_pass  http://internal_host:port/$request_uri$query_string;
```

Thanks,

@pcamacho

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found the way to rewrite the proxy_pass URL:

```
  location  /string_1/   {  

    if ($request_uri ~* "/string_1/(.*)") { 
            proxy_pass  http://internal_host:port/$1;
    }   

  }
```

Regards,

@pcamacho

Comment: don't do it hard way

Comment: This is actually better way. nginx does urldecoding for proxy_pass that just ends up /. Braindead, but that's how it works. This version however passes the url as-is, without decoding, which is correct and what would happen without a proxy.

Comment: After three hours of trial and error, your answer worked for me. Just what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: For whatever reason I have been having the hardest time getting my node-based server-side API application to set cookies for my React client-side application. I've tried setting *.domain.ext* for domain, for host (with *api.domain.ext* being the actual domain), tried leaving them out, they don't work - `document.cookie` is always empty. As soon as I used this method to proxy pass anything under *domain.ext/api/* to the Node app, cookies started working flawlessly with my React application. I'm going to link this answer in some of the other questions that are more specific to that. Thanks!

Answer (score 23):

It's really basic and simple. Just add `/path/` part to `proxy_pass` and nginx will replace `location`s prefix with that path. You need to replace `/string_1/` with `/`, so do it:

```
location /string_1/ {
    proxy_pass  http://internal_host:port/;
}
```

Comment: You should emphasize the latter slash, it's a big deal. Without it, does not work properly: http://serverfault.com/a/586614/262150

Comment: also notice that if the proxy_pass entry is using any other variable (like a variable for the hostname), nginx will stop adding the corrected `$uri`. You may workaround with a `rewrite ^/string_1(.*)  $1 break;` and then use `proxy_pass  http://$host/$uri;`. This `$uri` is the correct one, changed by the rewrite