# How to remove a subpath from an URL in nginx proxy_pass?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, proxypass

Here is the configuration for my reverse proxy server:

```
server {
  listen 8085 ssl;
  server_name  localhost;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://192.168.85.56:8080;
  }
}
```

For an incoming path, e.g.: `https://localhost:8085/path1/1/path2/`, I want to remove the `/1/`, so the resulting path will be `https://localhost:8085/path1/path2/`.

One constraint is that `path1` can change to any string.

Also, matching on any number instead of just `1` is also a valid solution.

How can this be done?

Edit:
My problem is very similar to [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/699695/nginx-proxy-pass-remove-url-substring?rq=1), except that I have a string, `path1`, that can vary.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `rewrite...break` inside the `location` block.

For example:

```
location / {
    rewrite ^(.*)/[0-9]+/(.*)$ $1/$2 break;
    proxy_pass http://192.168.85.56:8080;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

Comment: It worked with one caveat. The server I am running is a Spark history server and with this solution, I need to click the links to each "application history data" twice. Once a link has been clicked, it does not need to be clicked twice again. I suppose the `/1/` tells the server to load the history data into memory. Is there any workaround for this?