# nginx subdirectory as root along with other folders

Tags: nginx

The root (http://www.example.com/) will point to /var/www/wordpress

How can I allow each one to be viewable in browser?

```
working -- http://www.example.com
error -- http://www.example.com/wordpress2
error -- http://www.example.com/htmlsite
```

Here is the structure:

```
first wordpress: /var/www/wordpress
second wordpress: /var/www/wordpress2
static html page: /var/www/htmlsite

server {
root /var/www/wordpress;
index index.php;
...

location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location /wordpress2 {
  root /var/www/wordpress2;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location /htmlsite {
  root /var/www/htmlsite;
  try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

}
```

If I do this `root /var/www;` instead, then /wordpress2 and /wordpress3 works:

```
server {
root /var/www;
index index.php;
...

location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

location /wordpress2 {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /wordpress2/index.php$is_args$args;
}

location /wordpress3 {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /wordpress3/index.php$is_args$args;
}

location /htmlsite {
  root /var/www/htmlsite;
  try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

}
```

Comment: You need to define a server for each Wordpress site, not a location. Have a look at my tutorial, which has example config files: https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/hosting-wordpress-on-aws-tutorial-pt1-introduction-configuration-downloads/

Comment: @EEAA the question isn't that well worded, but I don't think it deserved to be put on hold. Suspect a non-native English speaker.

Comment: @Tim It was phantom edited since the original posting. The original had no questions in it. I'll re-open.

Comment: You could put wordpress2 and wordpress3 in one rule with a wildcard, see https://serverfault.com/a/787599/128892

Answer (score 7):

This should work the way you want to.

Since the URI is appended to the directory specified in `root` directive, we need to specify it only once. Only the `try_files´ has to be specified for each location separately.

```
server {
    root /var/www/wordpress;
    index index.php;
    ...

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location /wordpress2 {
        root /var/www;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /wordpress2/index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location /htmlsite {
        root /var/www;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

Comment: while your config passes `nginx -t` ... getting 404 error when browsing to both www.example.com/wordpress2 and www.example.com/htmlsite

Comment: True, I forgot that the directories for sites were different. I added proper `root` directives.

Comment: tried your edits and www.example.com/htmlsite is now working but www.example.com/wordpress2 is **not** working. Getting closer. Thanks!

Comment: What does nginx error log show?

Comment: not much in log but page has 404 error. I updated my post and include new test. See changed root and location. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have three Wordpress instances on three domains. In that case you need to define servers for each website and Wordpress install.

If you want multiple Wordpress installs on one domain then your approach is generally correct, but you need to define the handover to PHP. I have a good [tutorial on that](https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/hosting-wordpress-on-aws-tutorial-pt1-introduction-configuration-downloads/), but really you can just google "Nginx Wordpress tutorial" and find 100 tutorials.

Suggest you start with getting one working then add others.

Comment: Tried your google search suggestion and looked at first page results but only show single install without much suggestion to my situation. Thanks.

Comment: You need to describe your situation and problem better. You haven't stated your desired end state (one domain, many domains) and haven't said exactly what's wrong. Plus your Nginx config file having a lack of PHP fastcgi_pass shows you haven't really read or understood appropriate tutorials, or you haven't included your full config file.

Answer (score 0):

This is all you need.

```
    server {
            listen 80;
            root /var/www/wordpress;
            server_name example.com www.example.com;
            index index.php; 

    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        }

    location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png|woff|woff2|ttf|ttc|otf|eot)$ {
            expires max;
            log_not_found off;
        }


        location / {
            #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        }


     location /wordpress2 {
      root /var/www/wordpress/wordpress2;
      index index.php;
      try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

      location ~ /wordpress2 /(.+\.php)$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        }
     }

     location /htmlsite {
      root /var/www/wordpress/htmlsite;
      index index.php;
      try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

      location ~ /htmlsite /(.+\.php)$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: sorry I'm confused. www.example.com is working but I see your path include extra folder - do I need to include? /var/www/wordpress/wordpress2 or should it be /var/www/wordpress2

Comment: I assumed the "wordpress2" folder is in "wordpress" folder, if that's the case then leave it like that, otherwise use the respective path instead of the one I posted. :) as an example if the wordpress2 folder is in /var/www/wordpress2 then use the root as. location /wordpress2 {
  root /var/www/wordpress2;

Comment: This doesn't work, because nginx appends the URI to the location specified in `root` directive. That is, in this case if one requests `http://www.example.com/wordpress2/example.html`, nginx will try to show file `/var/www/wordpress/wordpress2/wordpress2/example.html`.

Comment: It works like this. when you visited the  example.com/wordpress2 the respective block which is the  "location /wordpress2 {" is called, and then its root path is used as the reference to look for the files to be called. since I use index index.php, the index.php is called in default.

Comment: The config for location /htmlsite failed when I use nginx -t (invalid number of arguments)

Comment: can you try it again. I think you might have not copied the last curly bracket which was out of the code block.

Comment: Did you test it also for static files inside `/wordpress2`?

Comment: yeah it works for both dynamic (PHP), and static contents fine.

Comment: I copy and pasted [http://imgur.com/a/Gkp3M] from your code and it does not pass `nginx -t` but once I remove that part test pass.

Comment: does at least example.com/wordpress2 work?

Comment: you have to use server_name example.com www.example.com; for www version to work.