# Nginx chooses a random location block

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I would like to redirect requests to different servers depending on path, therefore I am using the following http block in the Nginx configuration:

```
http {
  include  /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;
  index index.html index.htm;

  server {
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/staging.access.log main buffer=32k;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/staging.error.log error;
    listen      80;
    root        /dev/null;

    location / {
      proxy_pass        http://core:80;  # returns "Core Service"
    }

    location /page/ {
      rewrite ^/page(/.*)$ $1 break;
      proxy_pass        http://page:80;  # returns "Page Service"
    }

    location /auth/ {
      rewrite ^/auth(/.*)$ $1 break;
      proxy_pass        http://auth:80;  # returns "Auth Service"
    }
  }
}
```

As far as I understand the Nginx documentation, Nginx should use the best matching location block, therefore I would expect that `curl http://hostname/` should return "Core Service", `curl http://hostname/auth` "Auth Service" and `curl http://hostname/` "Page Service". Nginx however uses a random location block:

```
$ curl  http://hostname/
Core Service
$ curl  http://hostname/
Auth Service
$ curl  http://hostname/
Page Service
$ curl  -L http://hostname/page
Auth Service
$ curl  -L http://hostname/page
Auth Service
$ curl  -L http://hostname/page
Core Service
```

What is wrong with my configuration?

Comment: Check with `curl -v`

Comment: BTW, what are `core`, `page` and `auth` servers? May be you've mixed up them

Comment: @Alexey Thank you, with your hint I have found the problem: The `core`, `page` and `auth` server are virtual Docker servers. I thought this would not been relevant, but it was. The integrated Docker DNS server had resolved the host names somehow randomly, now with fixed IP addresses it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added trailing / character at the end of your each match, try to edit as follow:

```
location /page {
  rewrite ^/page(/.*)$ $1 break;
  proxy_pass        http://page:80;  # returns "Page Service"
}

location /auth {
  rewrite ^/auth(/.*)$ $1 break;
  proxy_pass        http://auth:80;  # returns "Auth Service"
}
```

Comment: Actually author should use slashes and don't need rewrite. http://serverfault.com/a/586614/211028

Comment: With your configuration it works, the real problem was a bug with the integrated DNS server from Docker and the usage of host names instead of IP adresses in the Nginx configuration.

Answer (score 0):

BTW, you should simplify your config:

```
server {
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/staging.access.log main buffer=32k;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/staging.error.log error;
    listen      80;

    location / {
      proxy_pass        http://core:80/;  # returns "Core Service"
    }

    location /page/ {
      proxy_pass        http://page:80/;  # returns "Page Service"
    }

    location /auth/ {
      proxy_pass        http://auth:80/;  # returns "Auth Service"
    }
}
```