# How to rewrite url to backend while preserving browser url in nginx ingress?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I'm trying to rewrite the path to the service while preserving the browser url with nginx ingress on kubernetes.

What I need is this:

- `http://example.com/path` => `http://service`
- `http://example.com/path/bar` => `http://service/bar`
- `http://example.com/path/file.css` => `http://service/file.css`

That is, make the `/path` be the root (or some different url) in the upstream server.

From what I see [here](https://serverfault.com/a/586614/229225), this is done using a trailing slash on the proxy_pass, but nginx ingress doesn't seem to have this option.

Is this possible nginx ingress?

Answer (score 14):

> Is it Possible on Nginx Ingress?

- Yes, In order to achieve it you can use [`rewrite-target`](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/).
- It will create a capture group and send it to the appropriate service. Here is an Ingress example:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: "rewrite"
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  rules:
    - http: example.com
        paths: 
          - path: /foo(/|$)(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: echo-svc
              servicePort: 80
```

> In this ingress definition, any characters captured by `(.*)` will be assigned to the placeholder `$2`, which is then used as a parameter in the `rewrite-target` annotation.

This ingress will do the following:

- Requests to **/foo** will be delivered to echo1-svc as **/**
- Requests to **/foo/bar** will be delivered to echo1-svc as **/bar**
- Requests to **/foo/file.css** will be delivered to echo-svc as **/file.css**
- Nginx Ingress uses [Path Priority](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/ingress-path-matching/#path-priority):

> In NGINX, regular expressions follow a first match policy. In order to enable more accurate path matching, ingress-nginx first orders the paths by descending length before writing them to the NGINX template as location blocks.

---

**Example:**

```
$ kubectl apply -f echo-ingress.yaml 
ingress.networking.k8s.io/echo-ingress created

$ kubectl get ingress
NAME           HOSTS          ADDRESS        PORTS   AGE
echo-ingress   mydomain.com   35.188.7.149   80      48s

$ tail -n 1 /etc/hosts
35.188.7.149 mydomain.com

$ curl mydomain.com/foo/bar
{"path": "/bar",
...suppressed output...
  "os": {"hostname": "echo-deploy-764d5df7cf-6m5nz"}
}

$ curl mydomain.com/foo
{"path": "/",
  "os": {"hostname": "echo-deploy-764d5df7cf-6m5nz"}
}
```

If you have any question let me know in the comments.

Comment: good answer. note that ingress-nginx has to be installed in the cluster to work. also this is interesting to know how to go about multipath : https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/6139 (thus making two ingress yaml files).

Comment: Missing pathType?

Comment: if we have diff services which have same "/' basepath, it is work?

Answer (score 0):

In short: yes it is. Make sure not to confuse nginx-ingress (which you use as a label in your question ) and ingress-nginx, those are different.
It works with ingress-nginx by installing it according to documentation.
The provided answer from @Will R.O.F. shows how and the documentation can be found here:
https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/ingress-path-matching/