# Nginx multi-domain and multi web servers with one public IP

Tags: nginx, domain

I have two web servers with different domain and only one public IP. I found that I can multi domain in the same IP and same server as bellow, but I would to open the website depending on the domain.
I tried

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  first.domain.com;
    return 301 http://192.168.1.10;
}
```

but this configuration change the url to `http://192.168.1.10` !
I want to see the `https://first.domain.com/request` rather than `http://192.168.1.10`/request

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nginx Redirect via Proxy, Rewrite and Preserve URL](https://serverfault.com/questions/586586/nginx-redirect-via-proxy-rewrite-and-preserve-url)

Comment: looks like what I'm looking  for, Thank you @djdomi